# Show that any continuous map $f:X\to Y$ is a constant.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X=\mathbb R$ with the cofinite topology and $Y=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology. Show that any continuous map $f:X\to Y$ is a constant.

My try:

Let $f:X\to Y$ be continuous. If possible let $a,b\ \ (a< b)\in\Im(f).$ Set $$I_1=\left(a-1,\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right),\\I_2=\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2},b+1\right)$$

Then $f^{-1}(I_1)$ and $f^{-1}(I_2)$ are nonempty disjoint open sets in $X$. Consequently both of them contain all but finitely many reals, which is impossible.

Am I correct?

Comment: Does continuity imply $f^{-1}(I_1)\cap f^{-1}(I_2)=\emptyset$

Comment: Yes, the proof looks correct to me. But now, for completeness, show that constant functions are continuous; it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: it is necessary to derive the contradiction that disjoint sets actually overlap.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: For otherwise $\exists~x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\in I_1\cap I_2$ but it is empty.

Comment: Oh yes... I overlooked it... it looks fine to me now...

Comment: @Shantipriya nice! If you'd like, you can post your attempt as an answer to the question.

Comment: @user99680 Constant functions are always continuous regardless.

Comment: @Vadim: I know; I thought the OP may want to go through the argument at least once, just for the sake of practicing; it is the type of thing IMHO you must do once before  dismissing.

Comment: @user99680 Yes, you are right about this. I was just saying that it is usually not necessary to include it "for completeness", but it is something that you should definitely know how to show immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is absolutely correct, so I just wanted to generalize it for you a bit.

Suppose you have a continuous function $f$ from an *infinite* set $X$ in cofinite topology into a *Hausdorff* set $Y$. If there were two different points in the image of $f$, you could take two disjoint nonempty open sets in $Y$ containing those points, and their preimages would be a) non-empty, b) open, c) disjoint in $X$, and that is not possible since $X$ is infinite and in cofinite topology.

So, your result is true in more general settings as well.